# How to show alert confirmation dialog from listview button in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-adapter, android-viewholder

I am trying to show the **confirmation dialog** after clicking on the **button in listview**.

I have **setOnClickListener** in my **CustomAdapter** in **getView** method.

but on click listener I am getting following error:

```
02-25 21:36:32.065 20631-20631/com.themsg.chat W/Toast: From com.themsg.chat, go ahead.
02-25 21:36:32.095 20631-20631/com.themsg.chat W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
02-25 21:36:32.095 20631-20631/com.themsg.chat W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:569)
02-25 21:36:32.095 20631-20631/com.themsg.chat W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:266)
02-25 21:36:32.095 20631-20631/com.themsg.chat W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-25 21:36:32.095 20631-20631/com.themsg.chat W/System.err:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
```

Here is my code:

```
holder.tvm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    chatroomMembers = getItem(position);

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "here", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                        .setTitle("Title")
                        .setMessage("Do you really want to whatever?")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                deleteUserFromChatrrom(chatroomMembers.getId(), SessionData.getInstance().getCurrentChatroom(), position);
                            }})
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: why you are not getting error `The method getContext() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}` in your toast line...

Comment: i mean you there is not method `getContext()` in `View.OnClickListener()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Class CustomAdapter you declare a variable mContext and a ArrayList data to ListView

```
    ArrayList<String> datasource;
    Context mContext;
```

Create a constructor:

```
    public AdapterAudio(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> data) {
    super();
    this.datasoure = data;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

When you call CustomAdapter from Activity, "Activity_Main.this" is Context you need

```
   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(Activity_Main.this, listAudio_hienthi10);
```

Now you have a Context, use variable mContext is declared to replace

```
    "getContext()", "v.getContext()"
```

Now you can Toast or show any dialog when click Button in CustomAdapter you want.
Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing getContext() with getApplicationContext()